# TableView HeaderSection Memory Allocation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, tableview

I am using an

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{    
    customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 24.0)];//custom view    
    // create the button object
    headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width, 18)];//header label    
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"section" ofType: @"png"]]];       
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"section" ofType: @"png"]]];    
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//text color of header label           
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];//font of header label        
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];    
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 24.0);//frame of header label

    if(searching)//checking searching {    
        headerLabel.text = @"  Search Results";//searching results as a text of header label    
    }       
    else {    
        if(section == 0)//checking which section is chosen   {    
            headerLabel.text = @"  Sponsored";//sponsored as header label
        }
        else {      
            headerLabel.text = @"  Unsponsored";//un sponsored as header label          
        }
    }

    if(searching)//checking searching {                  
        headerLabel.text = @"  Sök resultat";//sok resultant text as a header label                  
    }
    else {    
        if(section == 0)//checking which section is chosen {     
            headerLabel.text = @"  Sponsrade";//sponsorade as text of header label
        }                    
        else   {
            headerLabel.text = @"  Un Sponsrade";//usponsrade as text of header label
        }   
    }                

    [customView addSubview:headerLabel];//header label as a subview     
    //NSLog(@"endOfviewForHeaderInSection");        
    //[headerLabel release];                
    return customView;//returning custom view

    [customView release];       
    //NSLog(@"endOfviewForHeaderInSection");
}
```

on header section in table view to divide the table in two section,when i am scrolling table view up and down memory allocation increases very fast,but instead of using above mentioned code on header section there is no memory allocation and app works fine.But there is need of using of using above code on header section,I can not remove the code from the header and i want to reduce the memory allocation also.Is there any other way to sort out the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please look over code formatting you're posting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{       
    //NSLog(@"startOfviewForHeaderInSection");
    // create the parent view that will hold header Label

    customView = nil;

    [customView release];

    headerLabel =nil;

    [headerLabel release];

    customView = [[UIView alloc]init];

    headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

   // customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 24.0)];//custom view

    // create the button object
 //   headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width, 18)];//header label



    //customView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 24.0);

    //headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 24.0);//frame of header label
    //DetailedCoupon *detailedcouponObj = [[DetailedCoupon alloc]init];//object of detailed 

    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"section" ofType: @"png"]]];

    //customView.backgroundColor = [detailedcouponObj getColor:@"D7D8D1"];//background color

    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"section" ofType: @"png"]]];

    //headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   // headerLabel.opaque = NO;//opaque header label

    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//text color of header label

   // headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//highlighted text color of header label

   // headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];//font of header label

    headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];//font of header label

    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 24.0);//frame of header label

    NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];//object of NSUserDefault

    NSString *storeLanguage = [pref objectForKey:@"language"];//store language of string type

    if ([storeLanguage isEqualToString:@"English"])//comparison of language choosed
    {

        if(searching)//checking searching

        {

            headerLabel.text = @"  Search Results";//searching results as a text of header label

        }

        else {

            if(section == 0)//checking which section is choosed

            {

                headerLabel.text = @"  Sponsored";//sponsored as header label

            }

            else  

            {

                headerLabel.text = @"  Unsponsored";//un sponsored as header label

            }   

        }
    }

    else
         {

             if(searching)//checking searching

             {


                 headerLabel.text = @"  Sök resultat";//sok resultant text as a header label

             }

             else {

                 if(section == 0)//checking which section is choosed

                 {

                     headerLabel.text = @"  Sponsrade";//sponsorade as text of header label

                 }

                 else  

                 {

                     headerLabel.text = @"  Un Sponsrade";//usponsrade as text of header label

                 }  

             }

         }

    [customView addSubview:headerLabel];//header label as a subview

    //NSLog(@"endOfviewForHeaderInSection");

    //[headerLabel release];

    storeLanguage = nil;

    [storeLanguage release];

    return customView;//returning custom view

    [pref release];

    [customView release];

    //NSLog(@"endOfviewForHeaderInSection");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is poorly formatted in your post and hard to follow.

But what I see is: you may be leaking the customView since you return before releasing it.  You could autorelease it instead, before returning.

One possibility if this is the top section of the table is to use the table's headerView instead, which I believe you do not need to keep allocating repeatedly like the viewForHeaderInSection.    You may also try creating and caching the new instead of creating it over and over again.